# Why did Superman have a reversed symbol in some episodes of "Superman: The Animated Series"?

Tags: dc-animated-universe, superman-the-animated-series

Why did Superman have a reversed symbol in some episodes of "Superman: The Animated Series"? I'm not confusing him with Bizarro, the reversed symbol was even in episodes which are not related to Bizarro.

Comment: Your video link is dead. I've edited it out for the moment; please consider replacing it.

Comment: @Jenayah probably there is nothing to put there anymore, there may be no such videos and they may be deleted again in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It didn't. As you can see here:

[image]

[image]

you will notice that these are reversed from the Youtube video you link to. Because the Youtube video you link to was reversed from the original video, ***[to avoid Youtube's Content ID system](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?hl=en)***:

> Videos uploaded to YouTube are scanned against a database of files that have been submitted to us by content owners. Copyright owners get to decide what happens when content in a video on YouTube matches a work they own. When this happens, the video gets a Content ID claim.

Videos get uploaded Reversed, Cropped, and Bordered, to avoid being taken down.

***There is no way in <strike>Hell</strike> Apokolips that DC or the WB would have gone to print and aired an episode where Superman's chest insignia was reversed like that.***

Comment: Even his curly hair is the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why everyone does that. I couldn't imagine that there was an actual legal reason why reversing the images voided copyright claims. I never thought that YouTube was actually scanning the videos they have stored and compare them to other sources.

Comment: Nope, not to avoid legality, just to avoid a mechanical fingerprint match. Same is done with audio edits, pitch/speed increased.